# Discord.js | How do i make a command that sends to a specific channel by id

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How do I make my bot sends a message to another channel by id, like `!say 6969420420 hello`

I'm currently new to this whole discord bot kind of thing so please help me it would really helpful

I remember it was like `get cache find channel` or something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the channel from the client and send the message to that channel

```
 channel = client.channels.cache.get('6969420420');
    channel.send('hello');
```

You can read more about discord's Cache [here](https://discordjs-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs_cache.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use args to get id and get message to sending

```
client.channels.cache.get(args[0]).send(args[1]);
```

Comment: try this you need to set args first